# Typescript how to type custom key in an object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have a function like this:

```js
interface IUseTest {
  settings: {
    id: string
  }
};

const useTest = (properties: IUseTest) => {
  const { settings } = properties;
  
  const test = (
    item: {
     [settings.id]: string | number, // Error here
     [key: string]: any
    }
  ): object => {
    // function logic, doesn't matter
  };
  
  return {
    test
  };
};
```

I should set an item with required key which I get from the settings object, but I got the error:

> A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression
> whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.

what I have to do?

**UPDATE:** is there a way to not use an interface?

**UPDATE:** the item can be like this: `{ id: 'someId' }` or `{ key: 'someKey' }`

**UPDATE:** typescript's version is `4.0.3`

Comment: Hi, could you show how you would use the function, i.e.: how the parameter `item` should look?

Comment: @yifansong, hi, the item should looks like: `{ id: 'some-id' ...other }` or `{ key: 'some-key' ...other }`, that's means that object can have key `id` or `key` (`id` === `key`)

Comment: So the `item` parameter actually looks like this: `{ string: any, ...rest }` that first property name being `properties.settings.id`?

Comment: @yifansong, yep, that's right

Comment: does const assertion work?

Comment: @yifansong, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Generics and [Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types), like so:

```
interface IUseTest<T extends string> {
  settings: {
    id: T
  }
};

const useTest = <T extends string>(properties: IUseTest<T>) => {
  const { settings } = properties;
  
  const test = (
    item: { [settingsId in T]: string | number } & {
     [key: string]: any
    }
  ): object => {
    // function logic, doesn't matter
  };
  
  return {
    test
  };
};
```

Here, `<T>` is the generic and `{ [settingsId in T]: string | number }` is the Mapped Type.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
const settings = {
  id: 'id',
};
type Settings = typeof settings;
interface Item extends Settings {
  [key: string]: any;
}
const test: (item: Item) => object = (item) => {
  return {};
  // function logic, doesn't matter
};
```

Comment: is there a way to not use an interface?

Comment: I don't quite sure. I thought it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions).

```js
const settings = {
  id: 'id'
} as const;
```

That should fix your error. If you're running a typescript version lower than 3.4 then typecast your `id` property in `settings`.

```js
const settings = {
  id: 'id' as 'id'
};
```

Comment: what if I have this: `interface ITest { settings: { id: string } }`? and I get `id` parameter from it

Comment: I've updated the question, set more information about it